# Exception: No Impeller context is available iOS

Tags: flutter

I have built my app, using Flutter, and now came the time to test my app on an iOS Device.

I have some AssetImages that I am loading in my app from my assets folder, now problem is, when running my Flutter app on an iOS Device (iPhone) using an Emulator, I get an error called "Exception: No Impeller context is Available".

And my AssetImage is not loading at all.

On the flip side, all my assets load perfectly on an Android device.

Maybe I am missing something? What may be the cause of this error I am getting?

I'd love it if anyone could give me some pointers on what to do next.

I have tried looking for a solution to my problem via the internet, but have not found my issue anywhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a fix to my issue, disabling Impeller seems to be the way to go.

My Assets are loading perfectly on my iOS Emulator now.

Ran this in terminal

```
flutter run --no-enable-impeller
```

Comment: So there is no use of impeller anymore? If we are supposed to disable it what's the advantage?

Answer (score 4):

Hmm, I read over the other answers to this and their answer is to disable the Impeller rendering engine. IMO, this is not a great solution.

Doing so disables the default rendering engine used by Flutter - impeller. This may introduce more bugs and worse performance (slower rendering).

I fixed this by using `flutter clean` and then compiling and launching the app again on the iOS simulator.

So:

A) `flutter clean` and recompile

B) Disable it in Terminal `flutter run --no-enable-impeller` (NOT RECOMMENDED)

C) Disable Impeller by Info.plist entry  (NOT RECOMMENDED)

```
<key>FLTEnableImpeller</key> 
<false/>
```

Comment: If I disable it in "info.plist" will it affect the application in the release version?

Comment: @MostafaAlazhariy yes it will

Comment: @Nitrodist Could you please explain why B) and C) aren't recommended and what the flip sides are of doing that?

Comment: Doing so disables the default rendering engine used by Flutter - impeller. This may introduce more bugs and worse performance (slower rendering).

Answer (score 2):

You can do Two things

1. Run it in **Terminal**

> `flutter run --no-enable-impeller`

2. Or write this in **Info.plist**

> `<key>FLTEnableImpeller</key> <false/>`

**>Rebuild Your Project After<**

Path to Info.plist in flutter project:
ios/Runner/Info.plist